# WebGL / How to remove the dark edges that appear on the border with the transparent part of the image after applying the warp effect?

Tags: glsl, webgl, webgl2

Demo https://codepen.io/Andreslav/pen/wvmjzwe

[image: Scheme]

Scheme: Top left - the original.
Top right - the result.
Bottom right - rounding coordinates when extracting color.

The problem can be solved this way, but then the result is less smoothed:

```
coord = floor(coord) + .5;
```

How to make it better? Make it so that when calculating the average color, the program ignores the color of transparent pixels?

Maybe there are some settings that I haven't figured out..

---

**Updated the demo**

The result is even better after such an adjustment:

```
vec4 color = texture2D(texture, coord / texSize);
vec4 color_ = texture2D(texture, coordNoRound / texSize);
if(color_.a != color.a) {
    color.a *= color_.a;
}
```

On the preview: bottom left. But this is not an ideal option, the correction is partial. The problem is relevant.

Comment: Moved the glfx.js dependency into the demo itself for convenience.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a premultiplied alpha problem. And it's not as much of a glsl problem as it is a glfx problem.

Here's what happens:

Consider the RGBA values (range 0..1) of two adjacent pixels *at the edge* of your source image. They would be something like this:

```
[R    G    B    A  ] [R, G, B, A]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] [?, ?, ?, 0]
```

Meaning that there is a fully opaque, fully-white pixel to the left, and then comes a fully-transparent (A=0) pixel to the right.

But what are the RGB values of a completely transparent pixel?

They are technically ill-defined. This is what causes all sorts of mathematical problems when processing completely transparent pixels. In practice, pretty much every image processing software will put [0, 0, 0] there.

So the pixels are actually like this:

```
[R    G    B    A  ] [R, G, B, A]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What happens if your swirl shader samples the texture *halfway between* those 2 pixels? It just interpolates each value on its own, so you get [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]. That's color [0.5 0.5 0.5], with 0.5 Alpha. Which is gray, not white.

The generally chosen solution to this problem is *premultiplied alpha*. Which means that, for any given RGBA color, the RGB components are *defined* so that they don't range from `0 .. 1.0`, but instead from `0 .. A`. With that definition, color `[0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]` is now "0.5 A, with *maximum* RGB, which is white". One side effect of this definition is that the RGB values of a fully transparent pixel are no longer ill-defined; they must now be exactly [0, 0, 0].

Pixel values defined in premultiplied alpha are mathematically well-behaved when interpolation is applied.

As you can see, we didn't really change any values, instead, we just *defined* that our result is now *correct*. Of course, we still need to tell the other parts of the graphics pipeline of our definition. That means:

(1) You need to make sure that your *input* texture also has premultiplied alpha, i.e. all its RGB values must be multiplied with their alpha value. This is generally what game engines do, all their textures have premultiplied alpha (sometimes you can even see the black-ish edges in their textures in a normal image viewer). Either every pixel must already be edited in the source file, or you do the multiplication once for each pixel in the texture after loading the image.

AND

(2) You need to convince every alpha blending component in your rendering pipeline to use *premultiplied* alpha blending, instead of "normal" alpha blending. It seems you use the "glfx" framework, I don't know glfx, so I don't know how you can make it blend correctly. Maybe check the docs. In case you are using raw OpenGL/WebGL, then this is the way to tell the pipeline that it should assume premultiplied alpha values when blending:

```
gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_ADD); // Normally not needed because it's the default
gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

(This can be derived from the analyzing the formula for source-over alpha blending, but without the last division step.)

The above code tells OpenGL/WebGL that every time it's blending two pixels on top of another, it should calculate the final RGBA values in a way that's correct assuming that both the "top" and the "bottom" pixel has premultiplied alpha applied to it. There's also equivalent code for DirectX.

For higher level APIs (for example, GDI+), you can typically specify the pixel format of images, where there is a separation between RGBA and RGBPA (PARGB in backwards GDI+ nomenclature), in which case the API will automatically choose correct blending when that particular image is being drawn. That may not be true for glfx though. In essence, you always need to be aware whether the pixel format of your textures and drawing surfaces have premultiplied alpha or not, there is no magic code that always works correctly.

**For a quick fix**, it appears that the framework you're using performs alpha blending so that it expects *non-premultiplied* alpha values to come out of the pixel shader. So you could just *undo* the premultiplication by adding this at the end:

```
color.rgb /= color.a;
gl_FragColor = color;
```

But for correctness, you still need to premultiply the alpha values of your input texture.

Because for example at the rounded corners, your input texture contains pixels which are fully white, but are semi-transparent; their RGBA values in the source look like `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8]`. But in order for the linear interpolation in the texture sampler to work correctly, the values need to be for example `[0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8]`.

<sup>(Note that you could also solve the issue by having the RGB values of the completely transparent pixel be `[1, 1, 1]` instead of `[0, 0, 0]`, but you will have a really hard time convincing every asset creation tool in your pipeline to do that. And on top of that, it only works if you actually know what the imaginary color of the completely transparent pixel should be)</sup>

<sup>(Also note that using premultiplied alpha has other advantages too. Basically, it was an "accident" that happened as a result of an optimization in blending code - but it turned out that this optimization also fixes a bunch of other problems.)</sup>

Comment: dialer, thanks for the detailed answer!
Corrected version of the demo for posterity: https://codepen.io/Andreslav/pen/yLKEymr

Identified problem: Some of my shaders will have to be changed so that they work correctly.

Comment: What I did: _(1)_ Removed `premultipliedAlpha: false` (default `premultipliedAlpha: true`) in glfx.js; _(2)_ After adding the image to the texture, the first thing I do is premultiplication using an additional shader; `color.rgb *= color.a;`

Comment: @АндреславКозлов seems reasonable. But do note that most engines do the multiplication just *once* after loading the texture. Either that, or the engine assumes that the image color is already premultiplied in the image file, but that is difficult to achieve with normal image software.